# AngularJS $scope variable undefined when trying to access it

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I'm writing an Electron (node.js) app with an AngularJS frontend. Due to node.js running at OS level and Angular running at client level, the two speak to each other using IPC (or in this case, ipc implemented by https://github.com/develephant/electangular).

In this instance, I have a service which is used to fire an IPC message to the node app:

```
app.service('msgService', ['ipc', '$rootScope', '$q', function(ipc, $rootScope, $q){
    this.sendMsg = function(type, value) {
        var message = {
            type: type,
            value: value
        };

        ipc.send(message);
    };
}]);
```

This service is injected into, and called upon by a controller, main Controller:

```
app.controller('mainController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', 'electron', 'msgService', 'hey', function($scope, $rootScope, electron, msgService, hey){

    msgService.sendMsg('db_find', {});

    // I can see the variable inside this console.log
    console.log($rootScope);

    // I get undefined here
    console.log($rootScope.msg);

}]);
```

Once the node app has generated the request, it sends a message back via ipc which is then picked up by a piece of code in the .run section of the Angular app:

```
app.run(['$window', '$rootScope', function($window, $rootScope) {

    $rootScope.$on('electron-msg', (event, msg) => {
        $rootScope.msg = msg;
    });

}]);
```

The above simply sets a msg property on the $rootScope variable within run, which I then expect to be able to access from inside my controller. You'll notice by the comments on the console.log lines that I can access $rootScope and the value is returned, however when I try and individually log $rootScope.msg, I get 'undefined'. This is also true for attempting to set a variable from the $rootScope.msg variable - I get undefined.

I've tried everything with this one, and I'm completely at the end of my tether!

Any help much appreciated :)

**EDIT:**

Below is the output of console.log($rootScope); as requested:

```
Scope {$id: 1, $$childTail: ChildScope, $$childHead: ChildScope, $$prevSibling: null, $$nextSibling: null…}
$$ChildScope
    :
        ChildScope()
$$applyAsyncQueue
    :
        Array[0]
$$asyncQueue
    :
        Array[0]
$$childHead
    :
        Scope
$$childTail
    :
        Scope
$$destroyed
    :
        false
$$isolateBindings
    :
        null
$$listenerCount
    :
        Object
$$listeners
    :
        Object
$$nextSibling
    :
        null
$$phase
    :
        null
$$postDigestQueue
    :
        Array[0]
$$prevSibling
    :
        null
$$watchers
    :
        Array[2]
$$watchersCount
    :
        99
$id
    :
        1
$parent
    :
        null
$root
    :
        Scope
msg
    :
        Array[4]
notificationCount
    :
        0
notifications
    :
        Array[0]
online
    :
        true
__proto__
    :
        Object
```

Apologies for bad formatting! But you can see msg sitting within the $rootScope!

Comment: Please show the output of `console.log($rootScope)`...

Comment: why cant you use the app.run part of your code in your controller?

Comment: Is there any chance that the `ipc.send` is asynchronous?

Comment: try console.log(msg); inside the $rootScope.$on, just to see if the function is being called once or maybe twice...

Comment: I've updated my question with $rootScope output @MarcoS

Comment: @devqon I think it might be, however would that cause differences between logging a whole variable and access it's children?

Comment: @GustavoGabriel I've tried what you said just now - I can confirm it's only running once!

Comment: Yeah of course that would make it different. It could be that you log the `$rootScope.msg` **before** the async event is fired. You can test it by wrapping the log in a `$timeout(function() { // log }, 1000);`

Comment: Can you do like var msgs = $rootScope.msg; just before your first console.log? or maybe var root_scope = $rootScope;

Comment: @devqon I mean possibly, but I'm not sure I follow (apologies, I come from a PHP background). In my understanding, if I can access $rootScope.msg and see it populated with results, doesn't that mean that the async event has fired?

Comment: @devqon I just tested your theory and I think you may actually be correct. I added a console.log to the .run function within $on and also left in my original console.log lines. The $on console.log returns results BUT also, more crucially, runs after the console.logs in the controller.

Comment: With that in mind - how would I go about ensuring the async event has finished?

Comment: Ok posted an answer =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the electron library fires those messages asynchronous, which causes that the `$rootScope.msg` isn't populated yet when you do the logging.

You can of course just listen to the event in your controller:

```
msgService.sendMsg('db_find', {});

$rootScope.$on("electron-msg", (event, msg) => {
    // message done
    console.log(msg);
});
```

Though this will of course also catch any other messages that are send through the ipc service.

Comment: How would I then go on to access this variable from within index.html, for example in an ng-repeat? I have tried this and don't actually get anything from "sites in allSites" after setting $scope.allSites.

Comment: You can access `$rootScope` properties in any view by just using `$root.msg` in your html

Comment: That's awesome, I didn't know that. However, I am still a little unsure how to access $root.msg within ng-repeat - is it possible? I've tried ng-repeat="thing in $root.msg" but no luck

Comment: then first checkout what `$root.msg` is. Is it an array?

Comment: Sorry I don't like to bitch, but it seems like the other user has just copied my comments, and his answer is completely useless/has nothing to do with this. So I'm curious why you accepted his one as the answer?

Comment: You're totally right, I hadn't even realised! My apologies, your answer is accepted. Thanks a bunch for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in the comments, @Adam Thomason was having trouble with an async function being called after he was trying a console.log. To ensure he uses the data he wants after the function was executed, the following code worked for him.

```
angular.element(document).ready(function () {
    console.log('Hello World');
});
```

Hope it helps someone else as well =)

Comment: I used this function to set a $scope.allSites variable which I then wanted to access within a html file, however in an ng-repeat I don't receive any data.

Comment: $rootScope variables are accessible directly in your html like so: ng-repeat="current_msg in $root.msg"

Comment: Any idea how to access $root.msg within ng-repeat? I'm so close to having this working!

Comment: If $root.msg is indeed an array, it should work, check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/twizzlers/upafbksc/1/